# Could not proxy request (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

[image: frontend dockerfile]

```
FROM node:16.11.1 AS Production

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

[image: backend dockerfile]

```
FROM node:16.11.1 AS Production

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

[image: Docker Compose]

```
version: "3.8"
 
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend_service
    image: backend_service:1.0.0
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: backend
      target: production
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5001:5001

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend_service
    image: frontend_service:1.0.0
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: frontend
      target: production
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

[image: Could not proxy request (ECONNREFUSED)]
[image: Docker containers]

Hi guys, this is my first time posting this :)

I am trying to use docker to dockerize my project. It uses node.js and mongodb.
Everything was smooth, when i run compose build it and run docker compose up.
The frontend and backend was working well, individually, as the frontend is working, and the backend is working as well when the address is typed in.

However, the frontend is not connected to the backend, causing this error 500.
[image: error]

I would be super grateful for any idea why this is happening and how to fix it :) thanks!

I have tried changing the ports in my docker compose file, but it didn't seem to work

Comment: What error occurred in the web server?

Comment: Backend and Frontend Services in your docker-compose are 2 different machines (virtually...). So, localhost on your Frontend is really only your Frontend. And there is nothing listening on port 5001 on that Frontend machine. 
However, looking from your frontend, there is something listening on "http backend:5001" and that is the backend. If you only access the backend from the frontend, then you don't even have to add the Ports section in the Backend Service.